# azopy error RESPONSE Status: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: azure

I keep getting this error when trying to copy a file from azure file shares to azure blob

I have generated a SAS token for each but every time I run the command I get

"RESPONSE Status: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature"

azcopy cp "https://storage01.file.core.windows.net/test/test.txt?sastokenhere" "https://tempblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds?sastokenhere"

Comment: Can you share the SAS token for both source and destination?

Comment: i cant for security reasons

Comment: You can obfuscate the `sig` part of your SAS token before sharing. Without real storage account name, your SAS token can't be used.